# Explanation of Binary AND Operator

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

Can someone please explain the purpose of the bitwise, Binary AND Operator( & ) and how to use it? I was looking at different ways of making a `isprime` function and came across this.

```
def isprime(n):
    # make sure n is a positive integer
    n = abs(int(n))
    # 0 and 1 are not primes
    if n < 2:
        return False
    # 2 is the only even prime number
    if n == 2: 
        return True    
    # all other even numbers are not primes
    if not n & 1: 
        return False
    # range starts with 3 and only needs to go up the squareroot of n
    # for all odd numbers (counts by 2's)
    for x in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

I also looked at [Python Bitwise Operators Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/bitwise_operators_example.htm) but couldn't grasp it.

Comment: Please don't place tag information in your question title. The tag system here is extremely effective and doesn't need any help. :-) I also removed some unnecessary tags, as the two remaining ones are sufficient to identify your question's topic and allow it to be found in searches by future readers.

Comment: This is an unpythonic use of `&`.  It is not any faster than using `n % 2` and it is less clear.

Comment: Also, you might consider using the `all` function and a genex to replace the for loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One number AND another is the bits of one number masked by the bits of another number. If a number AND 1 is 0 (`not n & 1` would be `True`), that means it's divisible by two, since all multiples of 2 have a 0 as the rightmost binary digit.

```
  11 = 00001011 (Not divisible by 2)      28 = 00011100 (Divisible by 2)
&  1 = 00000001                         &  1 = 00000001
---------------                         ---------------
       00000001                                00000000
```

Comment: Awesome, this will come in handy. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For example,

12 & 7 =
1100 & 0111
= 0100 
= 4

For the isPrime function, the first condition checks whether it is 0 or 1. The second condition checks whether it is 2. The third condition then checks if (n&1), which is a check whether the number is even. Every even number when converted to binary form has 0 in its last digit. So for example,

14 & 1 =
1110 & 0001
= 0

14 is proved to be even and henceforth not prime.